# How to set Dropdwnlist value in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

> How to set value of dropdownlist items while editing.
>
> 1. First I had BindDropDown (no issue, i had done)
> 2. Second, OnEdit i want to set the dropdownlist selectecd value based on the value came from service call.

I had two html pages, First Page is Summary screen where i display list of records in table. Second Page is my City Form.
When i click on Edit button inside table it will redirect to second Page and i need to set all the values in the second form.

For Input type text : I am able to set City Name, City Code etc etc.
But for Dropdownlist value is not getting selected.

```
component.html


<form #cityform="ngForm">
<mat-select  placeholder="Select Country" disableOptionCentering name="CountryId"   [(ngModel)]="_city.CountryId"  >
<mat-option value="0">--Select Country--</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngFor="let _country of drpcountry" [value]="_country.value" >
                              {{_country.description}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</form>
```

> city.ts

```
export class city {
    public CityId: any;
    public CityCode: string;
    public CityName: string;
    public StateId: any;
    public CountryId: any;

}
```

.ts

```
        export class AddeditcityComponent implements OnInit {
         _city: city = new city();
        drpcountry:any;
        constructor(){}

        ngOnInit() {
         this.BindDropdown();
         this._city = "services call"
        }
         BindDropdown() {
  this._httpdrp.GetData(mdlcountry).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe(
            data => {
   this.drpcountry = data;
} );
         drpcountry=//Service call;
        }

    }
```

Update : 
Array of drpCountry

```
{CityId: 7, CityCode: "SUR", CityName: "Surat", StateId: 4, CountryId: 2}
```

Comment: please clarify more

Comment: Please, add more information about your problem

Comment: I had updated my Question

Comment: @ManishGoswami See this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssgylf

Comment: Show the data for `drpcountry`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the [value] ="_country.CountryId". The value of ngModel and value of  should be of having the same value which will bind the value while editing. so for example `_country.value=1` and `_city.CountryId=1` then while editing the value will be set in the dropdown list based on ngModel value.

component.html

```
<form #cityform="ngForm">
<mat-select  placeholder="Select Country" disableOptionCentering name="CountryId"   [(ngModel)]="_city.CountryId"  >
<mat-option value="0">--Select Country--</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngFor="let _country of drpcountry" [value]="_country.CountryId" >
                              {{_country.description}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</form>
```

Comment: _country have Value & Description, Value is DataValueField & Description is DataTextField

Comment: Can you please share drpcountry object.

Comment: Variable can be different but value of both the variable needs tobe same.

Comment: it is same, please see updated Questioon drpcountry object

Comment: now i am unable to select the items from the DropDownlist

Answer (score 0):

I would use the async pipe.

```
<form #cityform="ngForm">
  <mat-select  placeholder="Select Country" disableOptionCentering name="CountryId"   [(ngModel)]="city.CountryId"  >
  <mat-option value="0">--Select Country--</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of (drpcountry | async)?.drpcountry" [value]="country.value" >
                                {{country.description}}
  </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  </form>
```

```
  BindDropdown() {
    this.drpcountry = // A service that returns an observable
    /*
       Something like this
       listCity(): Observable<City[]> {
         return this.http.get<City[]>(this.url);
       }
    */
   }
```

This line allows that when the list of cities has been obtained, then it is shown.

```
*ngFor="let country of (drpcountry | async)?.drpcountry"
```